# How to ack or nack from KafkaListenerErrorHandler

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener and also there is a KafkaListenerErrorHandler configured. How can I ack or nack the event based on the exception type in the error handler class. Now how can I ack or nack from handleError method of KafkaExceptionHandler?

Code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaExceptionHandlerConfig {
    
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Bean({"kafkaContainerErrorHandler"})
    public ErrorHandler kafkaContainerErrorHandler() {
        return new KafkaContainerHandler(dLQRecoverer());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaDLQRecoverer dLQRecoverer() {
        return new KafkaDLQRecoverer(jmsTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler() {
        return new KafkaExceptionHandler(dLQRecoverer());
    }

}

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaExceptionHandler implements KafkaListenerErrorHandler {


    @Override
    public Object handleError(final Message<?> message, final ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends; you need to show your configuration and container properties (ack mode etc). Edit the question, don't try to put it in a comment.

Comment: Added the configuration code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KafkaListenerErrorHandler`s are intended for request/reply scenarios where the error handler might want to return a different reply after some failure.

Those error handlers do not currently have access to the `Acknowledgment` argument. I have opened a new feature issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2355

For custom error handling, you should implement a `CommonErrorHandler` (if one of the supplied ones does not do what you need).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just an additional question though. When we do acknowledgement.nack(10000), the message is being replayed after the mentioned delay but I am not able to receive other events between that period. Is there a work around where we can move the offset and allow other events to be polled?

Comment: No; that is how it is designed; you have to use the Non-Blocking retries mechanism to do what you want; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic - the failed message is moved to a different topic (with the consumption delayed for the specified time) and the main container continues to process other records.